# Closest Prime Number via Letters

Tags: c++, performance, primes

I'd like this code to be optimized and factorized, along with, perhaps, re-making it so it's more readable via introducing better functions and minimizing the lines needed for it to be human-readable (making the code more advanced than the cheap theatrics used here).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define l_max 26
char l[]= {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

void prinLabel()
{
    for(int i=0;i<l_max;i++)
    {
        if(i<10)
        cout<<l[i]<<" ";
        if(i>=10)
        cout<<l[i]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<l_max;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
}

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i=2;i<=n/2; i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int findClosestToRight(int x)
{
    int cunt=0;
    while(!isPrime(x) && x<=25)
    {
        cunt++;
        x++;
    }
    if(x>25)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return cunt;
}

int findClosestToLeft(int x)
{
    int cunt=0;
    while(!isPrime(x) && x>0)
    {
        x--;
        cunt++;
    }
    if(x<0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return cunt;
}

int endl(int n)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
        int choice1;
        cout<<"Please insert your choice: ";
        char character;
        cin>>character;
        character=toupper(character);
        choice1=int(character)-65;
        cout<<endl;

        char theClosest;

        if(isPrime(choice1))
        {
            cout<<"Your input is already prime: "<<l[choice1];
        }
        else if(findClosestToRight(choice1) == findClosestToLeft(choice1))
        {
            cout<<"Your choice is in the middle of 2 prime characters, thus, your results are:\n"<<l[choice1-findClosestToLeft(choice1)]<<" and "<<l[choice1+findClosestToRight(choice1)];
        }
        else if(max(findClosestToLeft(choice1),findClosestToRight(choice1)) == findClosestToLeft(choice1))
        {
            cout<<"The closest prime char is to the left and is equal to "<<l[choice1-findClosestToLeft(choice1)];
        }
        else if(max(findClosestToLeft(choice1),findClosestToRight(choice1)) == findClosestToRight(choice1))
        {
            cout<<"Tho closest prime char is to the right and is equal to "<<l[choice1+findClosestToRight(choice1)];
        }

        endl(4);

        prinLabel();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please [edit] to add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

Comment: BTW, in `choice1=int(character)-65`, what does the `65` mean?  That's highly opaque, and likely non-portable.

Comment: How can this code possibly work? You have two `endl`, one from `namespace std` and one defined in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialise character arrays like strings.
Instead of:

```
char l[]= {'a','b','c','d',.........,'y','z'};
```

Do:

```
const string l = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Thx to @Toby for reminding me. We need to make the `l` constant since it's used in many functions and might get changed, causing errors that are difficult to find. Like this possible typo:

```
if (l[n] = 'a') return true;
```

Most compilers will not give even a warning for what's wrong there.

In **`main()`** :

1. User input can be directly used for initialising **choice1**:

   ```
   int choice1 = int((toupper(getchar()))) - 65;
   ```
2. The functions `findClosestToLeft()` and `findClosestToRight()` are unnecessarily separate. Their result of their loops can be directly assigned to variables which will make the main() shorter:

   ```
   int a= /*body of findClosestToLeft(choice1) */;
   int b= /*body of findClosestToRight(choice1) */;
       if(isPrime(choice1))
           cout << "Your input is already prime: " << l[choice1];
       else if (b == a)
           cout << "Your choice is in the middle of 2 prime characters, thus, your results are:\n" << l[choice1 - a] << " and " << l[choice1 + b];
       else if (max(a, b) == a)
           cout << "The closest prime char is to the left and is equal to " << l[choice1 - a];
       else
           cout << "Tho closest prime char is to the right and is equal to " << l[choice1 + b];
   ```

   You will notice that I removed the last condition:

   ```
   if (max(a, b) == b)
   ```

   It's because any pair of numbers a,b which are false for the previous two conditions will fall under the third by default, and without any error.

If you want even fewer lines, then remove curly-braces from loops and conditions which execute a single statement. If it's done everywhere, it decreases by about 34 more lines. **But I do not recommend it. Makes reading harder.** Eg:
Instead of:

```
if (x>y)
{
    do_this();
}
else
{
    do_that();
}
```

You can instead write:

```
if(x>y) do_this();
else    do_that();
```

In **`endl()`** function either return something, like 0, or just make the function void, since a return is not necessary there. And change the function name too since there's already an identifier `endl` in the standard library. That is a source of errors.

Finally, replace all `cunt` with `count` everywhere it has been used.

---

**Here's the code after applying all the changes I mentioned:**

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const string l = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

void newl(int n = 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) cout << "\n";
}
void prinLabel()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<26; i++)
    {
        if (i<10) cout << l[i] << " ";
        else      cout << l[i] << "  ";
    }
    newl();
    for (int i = 0; i<26; i++) 
        cout << i << " ";
}
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
        if (n%i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Please insert your choice: ";
    int a, b, count=0, c = int((toupper(getchar()))) - 65; //c stand for choice

        for (; (!isPrime(c) && c <= 25); count++, c++) {}
        if (c>25) a=-1;
        else      a = count;
        for (count=0; (!isPrime(c) && c > 0); count++, c--) {}
        if (c<0)  return -1;
        else      b = count;

    if (isPrime(c))
        cout << "Your input is already prime: " << l[c];
    else if (b == a)
        cout << "Your choice is in the middle of 2 prime characters, thus, your results are:\n" << l[c - a] << " and " << l[c + b];
    else if (max(a, b) == a)
        cout << "The closest prime char is to the left and is equal to " << l[c - a];
    else
        cout << "Tho closest prime char is to the right and is equal to " << l[c + b];

    newl(4);
    prinLabel();
    return 0;
}
```